# Selenium qtwebdriver Example

Tags: qt, selenium, qml, qt5

I am working on test automating a qt 5.5.1 - qml Application on an embedded device.Is it possible to do on [Selenium - qtwebdriver?](https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver)  If so I would first like to try it on the Desktop and then on the device.

Does anyone know of a tutorial of how a basic qt qml Desktop application is automated?I couldn't find it online.Pardon my noobness. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yest it is possible.

- Check some example selenium tests here : https://github.com/cisco-open-source/selenium/tree/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/qtwebkit/quick_tests
- To run these tests check https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/tree/WD_1.X_dev/src/Test: (main.cc is the main class to run, the *DeclarativeViewTest.cc are the test applications)
- you can start from wiki: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Hybridity-And-View-Management