# Using QtWebDriver to create Qt's automated tests

Tags: python, qt, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to create automated tests for a **Qt's app** with `selenium` + `QtWebDriver`.

I have read the **QtWebDriver's wiki**,  and some questions on `stackoverflow`
like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616566/selenium-qtwebdriver-example) one

However, I'm still not able to use `QtWebDriver`. I don't understand
how to link `selenium` and `QtWebDriver` together. there are a lot of
questions that I can't answer.

How can I use `Python` to create automated tests for my own **Qt's App** based on `selenium` + `QtWebDriver` ?

How can I link my **Qt's app** with `selenium` + `QtWebDriver` ?

What is the next step after running `webDriver.exe` ?

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me or send me a tutorial with an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please show us the code you have and what issue you are running into.

Comment: Same problem. Need an example of using QtWebDriver with minimal Qt application. Next will be pulmonary understand.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use Python to create automated tests for my own Qt's App based on selenium + QtWebDriver ?

Once the WebDrIver is running with your application you can test it in python like any selenium test, e.g:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
    command_executor='http://ip_of_webdriver:9517'
)
driver.get('http://example.com/exampleform.html')

# select input
form = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='lastname']")[0]

# PRESS ENTER
form.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# etc...
```

> How can I link my Qt's app with selenium + QtWebDriver ?

- From Selenium just use the RemoteWebDriver
- To link your application with QtWebDriver:

  - include the libs and headers of QtWebDrivcer in your application's build environment. (You can rebuild WD from source for your platform if needed)
  - modify your application's main so that it starts the QtWebdriver
  - rebuild
  - example and instructions here: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Build-And-Run#to-build-and-run-your-own-binary
  - Once this is done, start your application
  - Then using Selenium you will be able to connect to Webdriver and automate your application
  - If you are using a native applcation, have a look here: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Hybridity-And-View-Management#hybrid-uis, in order to see how WebDriver navigates native/hybrid UIs